# The error "The local variable age may not have been initialized" occurs as a result of attempting to catch more than one exceptions

Tags: java, exception, initialization

The error "The local variable age may not have been initialized" occurs as a result of attempting to catch more than one exceptions.

Hi. After the previous question has been resolved, I decided to make a small alteration to the program by using JOptionPane to transform printing in the console to a simple GUI, and a new error has occurred. I tried to catch two specific exceptions named NumberFormatException and NullPointerException. NumberFormatException occurs as a result of inputting characters other than numbers in the blank space of JOptionPane.showMessageDialog, since the variable has been declared as double. NullPointerException occurs as a result of clicking the X sign or cancel button.
In order to catch NullPointerException, I added some extra code following NumberFormatException.
However, when testing running the program, the following error occurs in the console as a result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized
The local variable age may not have been initialized

at Welcome.main(Welcome.java:10)
```

Actually, in the beginning of the class I have already declared the variable age as double, despite this, the error of 'may not have been initialized' persists. Could you please provide a solution to this error? The error will not occur if the code catch(NullPointerException e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Program canceled.") does not exist.

By the way, in addition to the main question, could you please also explain the meaning and usage of 'null' inside the parentheses of JOptionPane.showMessageDialog. Thanks a lot.
My code is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Welcome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double age;
        while (true) {
            try {
                age = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "please enter your age and we will define your age group"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input Error. "
                        + "Please enter a number corresponding to your age only.", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Program canceled.");
                continue;
            }
            if (age < 0) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning!Negative values cannot hold true.",
                    "warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            else if (age <= 0.1) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a newborn.");
            else if (age <= 1) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are an infant.");
            else if (age <= 3) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a toddler.");
            else if (age <= 5) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a preschooler.");
            else if (age <= 13) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a school-aged child.");
            else if (age <= 19) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are an adolescent and a denarian.");
            else if (age <= 29) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a vicenarian.");
            else if (age <= 39) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a tricenarian.");
            else if (age <= 49) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a quadragenarian.");
            else if (age <= 59) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a quinquagenarian.");
            else if (age <= 69) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a sexagenarian.");
            else if (age <= 79) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a septuagenarian.");
            else if (age <= 89) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a octogenarian.");
            else if (age <= 99) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a nonagenarian.");
            else if (age <= 109) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a centenarian.");
            else if (age <= 150) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a supercentenarian.");
            else if (age > 150)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning!The value entered is too large to be processed.", "warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable. Also make it a habit to give your variables a value right when you declare them (`double age = 0.0;` above the `while` loop).

Comment: Hi JustAnotherDeveloper. Thanks for the suggestion. I have approved the improved edit suggested by the system itself. It should look readable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move all the age validation login inside the `try` block, where the `age` variable is 100% defined. Like that:

```
try {
    // here you initialise the "age" variable
    final double age = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "please enter your age and we will define your age group"));
    
    // here you work with the "age" variable
    if (age < 0) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning!Negative values cannot hold true.",
                    "warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    else if (age <= 0.1) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a newborn.");
    else if (age <= 1) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are an infant.");
    else if (age <= 3) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a toddler.");
    else if (age <= 5) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a preschooler.");
    else if (age <= 13) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a school-aged child.");
    else if (age <= 19) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are an adolescent and a denarian.");
    else if (age <= 29) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a vicenarian.");
    else if (age <= 39) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a tricenarian.");
    else if (age <= 49) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a quadragenarian.");
    else if (age <= 59) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a quinquagenarian.");
    else if (age <= 69) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a sexagenarian.");
    else if (age <= 79) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a septuagenarian.");
    else if (age <= 89) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a octogenarian.");
    else if (age <= 99) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a nonagenarian.");
    else if (age <= 109) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a centenarian.");
    else if (age <= 150) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a supercentenarian.");
    else if (age > 150)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning!The value entered is too large to be processed.", "warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input Error. "
                        + "Please enter a number corresponding to your age only.", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Program canceled.");
                continue;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I tried it, which actually works! By the way, what does 'final' do in the code?

Comment: If my answer helped you, I'd appreciate if you mark my answer as accepted :)
Answering your question about "final": when this keyword is applied to the variable, means that this variable can be defined only once and then can not be re-defined. See more: https://www.baeldung.com/java-final

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if your code enters the following lines of code, the variable age will not actually be valued:

```
     catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input Error. "+ "Please enter a number corresponding to your age only.", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Java checks at compile time whether all variables have been correctly initialised. If the compiler considers that a variable may not have been initialised before the next instruction, this error is obtained.

You can solve this problem by simply initialising the variable:

```
     catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        age = 0D;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input Error. "+ "Please enter a number corresponding to your age only.", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

But I think that the proper way is:

```
     catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input Error. "+ "Please enter a number corresponding to your age only.", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        continue;
    }
```

Regarding your second question, concerning the
`showMessageDialog`, you can read in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object)) that:

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message) throws HeadlessException
    Brings up an information-message dialog titled "Message".
    Parameters:
        * parentComponent - determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is used
        * message - the Object to display
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say someone enters "hello" in the popup. The `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` method returns just fine, and `"Hello"` is handed to `Double.parseDouble`. This causes `NumberFormatException` to be thrown, and thus code switches to the catch block.

This catch block will print a message about needing to enter a number and then.. code just continues. After all, catching means you handle it (if you want to do something but then continue with the exception process, then re-throw it, or do something else to affect control flow, such as `continue;` which you DO do in the NullPointer catch block!)

Code continues into `if (age < 0)` and this code cannot be executed as `age` is unset in this case. The compiler knows this and will refuse to compile it.

The primary solution here seems to be to write control flow such that the `if (age < 0)` block is never ever 'hit' if the user doesn't enter a number in the first place. You know how - you're doing it with a while loop and that `continue;` statement in the other catch block.

Alternatively, pick an age that functions as a default or placeholder to indicate the user hasn't entered something yet. But that doesn't sound like the best solution for this case - you don't want to process the age until the user actually enters one.

Comment: Though I am struggling a bit to understand, thanks for the answer!